# Microsoft Project 2013 - Auto leveling according to Resource Availability

Tags: tasks, ms-project-2013

I am building a project plan on Microsoft Project 2013 and can't understand why it is not allocating a resource.

I have a task set as auto scheduled, fixed work, with a 7 day effort assigned to a single resource at 100%.

The resource has a limited availability and some days can only work 50% on the project (see image).

[image: Resource Availability]

When I hit the Level All button, Project doesn't allocate the resource to the task on 08-03-2019 at all:

[image: Task with 50% resource]

However, if I switch the resource's availability to 100% on 08-03-2019, the Level All button allocates the resource on that day:

[image: Task with 100% resource]

So my question is: what should I be doing differently so that the resource gets allocated to the task according to the availability defined in Resource Availability?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mauricio, There are three options (the last is easiest):

1. For 08-03-2019, set the resource availability to 100% (as you've done), then level.  Then in the resource usage view for the task, manually adjust the hours for 08-03-2019 from 8h to 4h.  This will remove 4h of work from the task, which you will need to add back at the end.
2. For 08-03-2019, keep the resource availability at 50%, then level.  Then in the resource usage view for the task, manually adjust the hours for 08-03-2019 from 0h to 4h.  This will add 4h work to the task, which you will need to remove at the end.
3. For 08-03-2019, set the resource availability to 100%, then create a resource calendar exception for that day - "Half-time Day,"  with working time from 08:00 to 12:00.  Re-level. Done.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Went for option 3. Besides being the easiest to implement, it's the easiest to maintain in my case, as all restrictions are on the resources.

Comment: Yep.  In fact, I'd probably do the whole deal using resource calendars rather than the availability matrix.  The only real downside (compared to the availability matrix and leveling) is that the Gantt bar doesn't split around non-working times.  Either approach requires an add-in for adequate critical path analysis.